# tcl script error on ns2 (no such variable)

Tags: tcl, ns2

I tried to run the example code available here: http://simula.stanford.edu/~alizade/Site/DCTCP_files/dctcp-ns2-rev1.0.tar.gz

As per the readme file, the patch was successfully applied but on executing the example code, the following error was obtained:

```
ns: myTrace file3: can't read "dctcp_alpha_": no such variable
    while executing
"subst $[subst $var]"
    (procedure "_o154" line 5)
    (Object next line 5)
    invoked from within
"_o154 next dctcp_alpha_"
    ("eval" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"eval $self next $args"
    (procedure "_o154" line 18)
    (Agent set line 18)
    invoked from within
"$tcp($i) set dctcp_alpha_"
    (procedure "myTrace" line 8)
    invoked from within
"myTrace file3"
```

How could this be solved?

Comment: Well, `subst $[subst $var]` is _awful_ code, and `set $var` would (probably) be better (or the code is even more awful than I thought). But that probably wouldn't fix the problem. Did you write `$tcp($i) set dctcp_alpha_` and what do you expect it to do?

Comment: Thanks a lot @DonalFellows for your kind reply. I am very new to tcl and this is the first tcl code I have seen in my life which is obviously not written by me, so unfortunately I cannot answer what I expect $tcp($i) set dctcp_alpha_ to do. The code is here: http://goo.gl/5HeO9y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build example : tar xvf ns-allinone-2.35_gcc482.tar.gz

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNSGJCZ2YzUGJDVk0/view?usp=sharing

cd ns-allinone-2.35/ns-2.35/

patch -p1 --ignore-whitespace -i dctcp.patch

cd ../

./install

cd ns-2.35/

sudo make install

cp ns ns235-dctcp

sudo cp ns235-dctcp /usr/local/bin/

- Run the simulation : **ns235-dctcp** simpleDumbbell.tcl

.. The files mytracefile.tr 2.1MB, thrfile.tr 10.2kB are created. ( And queue.tr : 0B ).

Your errors : You are probably using a wrong executabe 'ns'.

The safe way is a copy of the DCTCP patched 'ns', with a new name.

And with a location in a system PATH, like /usr/local/bin/ns235-dctcp

  -

Answer (score 0):

I used to have exactly the same problem as you mentioned:

```
  ns: myTrace file3: can't read "dctcp_alpha_": no such variable 
           while executing
  st $[subst $var]"
       (procedure "_o154" line 5)
       (Object next line 5)
       invoked from within
    ...
```

1.The problem is you needs to **compile** after running the patch.

as [Knud Larsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4491743/knud-larsen) mentioned in his answer, after running following patch:

```
cd ns-allinone-2.35/ns-2.35/

patch -p1 --ignore-whitespace -i dctcp.patch
```

You need to go to the /ns-allinone-2.35/ folder, and do the compiling:

```
cd ../

./install

cd ns-2.35/

sudo make install
```

2. Different from [Knud Larsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4491743/knud-larsen), I did not rename another *ns*. I run the simulation directly with *ns* command:

   ns simpleDumbbell.tcl

And it works for me.

Hope this helps : )

Answer (score 0):

```
ns: _o83 selfish: 
    (_o83 cmd line 1)
    invoked from within
"_o83 cmd selfish"
    invoked from within
"catch "$self cmd $args" ret"
    invoked from within
"if [catch "$self cmd $args" ret] {
set cls [$self info class]
global errorInfo
set savedInfo $errorInfo
error "error when calling class $cls: $args" $..."
    (procedure "_o83" line 2)
    (SplitObject unknown line 2)
    invoked from within
"_o83 selfish"
```